# Weird indented space on firefox

Tags: html, css

Working on a little project and for some reason, the CSS has created an indentation and I have no idea why. It seems like the margin is creating it but all items in the column have the same top margin so I dont understand why only one of them is different from the others.

Details details details I dont know why I need more details and things this is annoying I have explained my predicament.

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li class="navbar-item"> <a href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
    <li class="navbar-item"> <a href="recent.html">Browse</a> </li>
    <li class="align-right"><input type="email" name="" placeholder="example@email.com"></li>
    <li class="align-right"> <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Password"> </li>
    <li class="align-right"> <button type="submit" name="button">Sign In!</button> </li>
  </ul>
</nav>



<div class="jumboboi allinsidejumboboi">
  <div class="">
    <h1>Hey there, wanna sign up?!</h1>
    <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
      <label for="emailInput">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" name="emailInput" placeholder="example@email.com" required>
      <p><button type="submit" name="signUp">Sign Up!</button></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>




<div class="content-columns">
  <p class="flex-height"><img class="fifth-width" src="static/Bootstrap.png" alt="">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p class="flex-height"><img class="fifth-width" src="static/Bootstrap.png" alt="">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p class="flex-height"><img class="fifth-width" src="static/Bootstrap.png" alt="">
  </p>
  <p class="flex-height"><img class="fifth-width" src="static/Bootstrap.png" alt="">
  </p>
</div>



<div class="jumboboi-reverse">
  <div class="">

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.jumboboi{
  background: linear-gradient(#4040cf,#f2f0e9);
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right:-10px;
  height:200px;
  margin-top:-17px;
}
li a{
  padding-top:7px;
  display:block;
  width:80px;
  color:#d1cec5;
  text-align: center;
}
nav{
  height:50px;
  margin-top:-18px;
  margin-right:-15px;
  margin-left:-15px;
  background-color: #333333;
}
.jumboboi-reverse{
  background: linear-gradient(#f2f0e9,#4040cf);
  margin-top:40px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right:-10px;
  height:200px;
  margin-bottom:-10px;
}

.allinsidejumboboi{
  text-align: center;
  padding-top:5%;
  padding-bottom:5%;
}

body{
  background:#f2f0e9;
  color:#333333;
}
.content-columns{
  column-count:auto;
  column-width:300px;
  column-gap: 10px;
}
.navbar-item{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100px;
}
li{
  float:left;
}
.fifth-width{
  max-width:100%
}
.flex-height{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction:column;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` from `.flex-height` since that's not doing anything, and add `margin: 0 0 1em 0;` to remove the top margin from your paragraphs while keeping some bottom margin, and now the tops of your columns will align. Update snippet:

```css
.jumboboi{
  background: linear-gradient(#4040cf,#f2f0e9);
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right:-10px;
  height:200px;
  margin-top:-17px;
}
li a{
  padding-top:7px;
  display:block;
  width:80px;
  color:#d1cec5;
  text-align: center;
}
nav{
  height:50px;
  margin-top:-18px;
  margin-right:-15px;
  margin-left:-15px;
  background-color: #333333;
}
.jumboboi-reverse{
  background: linear-gradient(#f2f0e9,#4040cf);
  margin-top:40px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right:-10px;
  height:200px;
  margin-bottom:-10px;
}

.allinsidejumboboi{
  text-align: center;
  padding-top:5%;
  padding-bottom:5%;
}

body{
  background:#f2f0e9;
  color:#333333;
}
.content-columns{
  column-count:auto;
  column-width:300px;
  column-gap: 10px;
}
.navbar-item{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100px;
}
li{
  float:left;
}
.fifth-width{
  max-width:100%
}

.flex-height {
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li class="navbar-item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-item"><a href="recent.html">Browse</a></li>
    <li class="align-right"><input type="email" name="" placeholder="example@email.com"></li>
    <li class="align-right"><input type="password" name="" placeholder="Password"></li>
    <li class="align-right"><button type="submit" name="button">Sign In!</button></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="jumboboi allinsidejumboboi">
  <div class="">
    <h1>Hey there, wanna sign up?!</h1>
    <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
      <label for="emailInput">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" name="emailInput" placeholder="example@email.com" required>
      <p><button type="submit" name="signUp">Sign Up!</button></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="content-columns">
  <p class="flex-height"><img class="fifth-width" src="static/Bootstrap.png" alt="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p class="flex-height"><img class="fifth-width" src="static/Bootstrap.png" alt="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p class="flex-height"><img class="fifth-width" src="static/Bootstrap.png" alt="">
  </p>
  <p class="flex-height"><img class="fifth-width" src="static/Bootstrap.png" alt="">
  </p>
</div>


<div class="jumboboi-reverse">
  <div class="">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's pretty annoying that the only browser that the 'display: flex and flex-direction: column' works on is firefox, I like the way it looks and the way it functions. It still looks like butt in any other browser.. GET WITH THE TIMES CHROME! :p